# Fill a drop-down list parameter with specific available values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that creates report from a SQL table:

```
 id  type    name
 1   fruit   wilk
 2   fruit   scot
 3   paper   jon
 4   pen     brad
 5   tape    lin
 6   water   james
```

The report has two data sets: one feeds query for report, and the other feeds data to parameter. So in the report the multi-value parameter gets its values from dataset2.

```sql
-- dataset1::  
select ID, TYPE, name from table1 where type in (@types)

-- dataset2::
select TYPE from table1
```

The report is generated based on type selected from dropdown list (which is a multi select list).

For example if we select "fruit" the report displays:

> wilk, scot

If we select "water":

> james

Now the thing is that I need to create a name for all the values "TAPE", "pen", and "paper", say the name "STATIONARY", such that the dropdown list should show only:

> fruit, stationary, water

And when I select "STATIONARY" from thedropdown list the report should display:

> jon, brad, lin (all 3 have some form of stationary, i.e paper, pen, tape)

And when I select type as "STATIONARY" and "water" it should display:

> jon, brad, lin, james

Answer (score 1):

Just from the hip here.

Consider adding a category field to your table.  So for your fruit and water you could have a category called "Food", and for your pen, paper, and tape the category would be called "stationary".

Add another dataset to your report called "category".

```
SELECT Category FROM table1
```

Add another parameter that is a multiple selection of your new data set called @Category.

In your main query add:

```
...AND Category IN (@Category)
```

**EDIT**

Keep in mind this advice completely ignores normalization in your database.  I understand that is not the intent of your question but it is something you should always consider.  If it were me I would even add a category table.  Then with the "table1" as you call it I would add a foriegn key pointing at an ID in the category table.  You can even see this issue with your type column.  Notice how fruit is used more than once.

Comment: +1, the question sounds very much like the best answer would be to first do some normalization work in the database, making the SSRS problem very straightforward to fix.

Comment: Completely agree. I never know if someone is walking into a situation with a database or has the luxury of making those quick modifiations to set the project on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create another couple of tables for this called `Item` and `ItemType`.

`ItemType` has two fields: `ItemTypeId` (the auto-incrementing primary key) and `Name`. `ItemType` will have values like:

```
ItemTypeId    Name
1             Food
2             Stationery
```

`Item` has three fields: `ItemId` (the auto-incrementing primary key), `Name` and `ItemTypeId` (from the `ItemType` table above). It looks like this:

```
ItemId  Name   ItemTypeId
1       Fruit  1
2       Paper  2
3       Pen    2
4       Tape   2
5       Water  1
```

Add the `ItemId` field to `table1` and remove the `type` field, so it now looks like:

```
 id  ItemId  name
 1   1       wilk
 2   1       scot
 3   2       jon
 4   3       brad
 5   4       lin
 6   5       james
```

We now know the type of the item from the link to the `ItemType`.

Create two parameters: `@ItemTypes` and `@Items` as multi-value.

`@ItemTypes` populates from the `ItemType` table:

```
SELECT ItemTypeId, Name FROM ItemType
```

`ItemTypeId` is the `Value` and `Name` is the `Label`.

`@Items` populates from the `Item` table but is filtered on the `@ItemTypes` parameter like so:

```
SELECT ItemId, Name FROM Item WHERE (ItemTypeId IN @ItemTypes)
```

`ItemId` is the `Value` and `Name` is the `Label`.

Now when you select `@ItemTypes` in the first parameter, the second parameter will only show items of that type.

Okay, back to your query. Your main query now looks like:

```
SELECT Item.Name AS ItemName, ItemType.Name AS ItemTypeName, table1.Name
FROM table1
INNER JOIN Item ON Item.ItemId = table1.ItemId
INNER JOIN ItemType ON ItemType.ItemTypeId = Item.ItemTypeI
WHERE (ItemType.ItemTypeId IN @ItemTypes)
AND (Item.ItemId IN @Items)
```

and I think our work here is done.